# PHP Image upload not working?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

below is the code of the form to submit text and/or upload an image

```
<form id="comments" action="insertcomment.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Comment: <input type="text" name="comment" id="commentfield">
    <br>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    Image URL (Limit: 1MB): <input type="file" name="image">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

and when the user clicks the submit button it goes to this php script

```
<?php

include('../c_database.php');

$timeSet = date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

$User = $_COOKIE['username'];
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['comment']);
$time = date(DATE_RFC822);

        if($_FILES['image']['size'] <= 1048576){

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "bmp", "tiff", "xtiff");

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));

        if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")

        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")

        || ($_FILES["new_image"]["type"] == "image/png")

        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))

        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/bmp"))

        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

{

if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {

$error_message = $_FILES["image"]["error"];

} else {

if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))

{

$error_message = $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " " . $LANG['image_exist'];

} else {

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

// success
$image_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

} else {

$error_message = "Upload Failed!";

}

}

}

} else {

$error_message = "Error: May be different ext or size";

}

}

$imagepath = 'images/'. $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$commentQuery = "INSERT INTO comments (username, comments, time_added, imagepath) VALUES ('$User' ,'$comments' ,'$time' ,'$imagepath')";
$executeCommentQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $commentQuery);

if($executeCommentQuery){

$user = $_COOKIE['username'];

$commentsMadeUpdate = "UPDATE login SET Comments_Made = Comments_Made +1 WHERE Username='$user'";
$executeUpdateQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $commentsMadeUpdate);

 echo '<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Comment</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">      </script>
</head>

<body>';
  echo 'Comment and/or image uploaded successfully';

  echo '<script>location.href="comments.php"</script>';

  echo '
 </body>
 </html>';

 } else {

echo '<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comment</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">    </script>
</head>

<body>';
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
echo '
</body>
</html>';
}

?>
```

this code should insert the comment, and move the uploaded image to the images folder and store the image path in the database however when the user clicks submit their comment gets inserted but not the image path and the image is not in the temp folder or the images folder, can someone tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: @DanielA.White i get a parse error but it has no information apart from that its on line 12

Answer (score 1):

The highest level conditional, where you are checking the file type, might never be triggered due to a possible typo: $_FILES["new_image"]["type"]

Should that be: $_FILES['image']['type'] ?

You should also consider catching exceptions for your database operations:

```
mysqli_query(..) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: I tried that but i just get a parse error on line 12 but thats all the information it gives

Comment: @RyanKelly On closer inspection.. you have an extra ')' ::  ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) <-- remove the extra ')'... and that should be 'jpg' not 'pjpeg'.. the code might be riddled with other typos..